# Processing huge files of GPS data, extracting fields from five lines before and after each timestamp

Tags: csv, linux, shell, geospatial

I have written a shell script to process my huge data files (each one having around 7,000,000 lines ~ a weeks data in a single file).

Here is a sample of my data file (i.e., input file) structure:

> ```
> 808 836 204 325 148 983
> 908 836 203 326 148 986
> 8 835 204 325 149 984
> 108 835 204 325 148 984
> 208 836 204 326 149 984
> 308 834 203 325 149 985
> 408 836 204 326 149 983
> 508 834 203 325 149 985
> 20130402,123358 0 $GPRMC,123358.000,A,5056.3056,N,00622.5644,E,0.00,0.00,020413,,,A*67
> 608 834 203 325 150 985
> 708 834 204 326 150 986
> 808 836 204 325 151 983
> 908 835 204 325 153 984
> 8 816 202 325 153 973
> 108 836 204 324 156 984
> 208 835 204 325 157 983
> 308 834 202 324 158 985
> 408 835 203 325 158 985
> 508 836 203 324 160 984
> 20130402,123359 0 $GPRMC,123359.000,A,5056.3056,N,00622.5644,E,0.01,0.00,020413,,,A*67
> 608 835 204 325 162 986
> 708 836 204 324 164 983
> 808 835 202 324 165 986
> 908 836 204 324 167 983
> 8 836 202 324 168 985
> 108 835 203 325 170 986
> 208 836 203 324 171 983
> ```

I have an instrument whose counter provides the data every 0.1 second while the GPS provides its measurement in between every 1 second. For every GPS measurement, I want to extract the above 5 lines and below 5 lines of my instrument record simultaneously. I don't want all 6 elements from my instrument record. From my instrument record, I require only the 5th elements of the above and below 5 lines against each GPS record. In addition, from the GPS record, I want to extract the date (1st element), time (2nd element), latitude and longitude.

From the sample example, I shall obtain this:

> ```
> 20130402 123358 5056.3056 00622.5644 148 149 149 149 149 150 150 151 153 153
> 20130402 123359 5056.3056 00622.5644 156 157 158 158 160 162 164 165 167 168
> ```

In order to extract and arrange the data, I have initially written Matlab and IDL code.

I then again wrote a shell script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
clear
# Program to read *.bin files
# Data directory
DATAPATH='/home/xyz/datasets/2013_04_09/'

# Output data directory
OUTPATH='/home/abc/data_1/'
count=1; 

# Read the files sequentially
for file in $DATAPATH*.bin; do
  INFILE=$file;      # Input file   
  INFILENAME=`echo $INFILE | awk -F'/' '{print $7}'`
  SUFFIX="1.txt"
  OUTFILE="$OUTPATH${INFILENAME:0:18}$SUFFIX"   # Output file  
  TEMPFILE="${OUTPATH}tempresult_sed.txt"
  awk '{if(length($0) >= 79) print NR,",",$0}' $INFILE | sed 's/ /,/g' > $TEMPFILE
  lines=`cat $TEMPFILE | awk -F, '{print $1}'`
  lat=`cat $TEMPFILE | awk -F, '{print $10}'`
  lon=`cat $TEMPFILE | awk -F, '{print $12}'`
  date=`cat $TEMPFILE | awk -F, '{print $4}'`
  time=`cat $TEMPFILE | awk -F, '{print $5}'`
  array_lines=($lines)
  array_time=($time)
  array_lat=($lat)
  array_lon=($lon)
  array_date=($date)
  count=${#array_lines[@]}  # Number of data records
 for i in `seq 1 $count`; do 
    idx=$(($i-1))
    echo ${array_lines[$idx]} ${array_date[$idx]} ${array_time[$idx]} ${array_lat[$idx]}  ${array_lon[$idx]} `sed $((${array_lines[$idx]}-5))","$((${array_lines[$idx]}-1))"!d" < $INFILE | awk '{print $5}'` `sed $((${array_lines[$idx]}+1))","$((${array_lines[$idx]}+5))"!d" < $INFILE | awk '{print $5}'`
  done > $OUTFILE
  rm -f $TEMPFILE  # Remove the temporary file
  let count++;
done
```

In the script for cross-checking, I have included the line number from the input file with `${array_lines[$idx]}` in the code. I started running my shell script on the server. It took more than two days but still not even a single input file (with 7,000,000 lines) was completed. Until now, around 1.5 million lines were only written to my `OUTFILE`. Just pulling all the GPS lines (i.e., strings of length = 80) and writing to a `TEMPFILE` is taking 1 minute while the extraction of the 5th element from above and below 5 lines of the instrument counter data and arranging as specified is taking long.

I really require someone who can suggest/correct my code so that my computation will be faster. I have already posted my script in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612290/how-to-extract-lines-in-between-a-file-read-a-part-of-a-string-with-linux-shel) but for a different query. So, don't be panic about cross-posting. Please suggest ways in which I can extract the data from my input file structure in very less time of computation from a huge file.

Comment: Sorry but shell script isn't the right tool if you want to get performance. You'll end up spending your time forking to call command like ``awk`` ``sed``. Try out a real programming language such as Perl / Python / C.

Comment: @Slaven - I am not having experience with writing Perl scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The details of your question are entirely unclear to me. I have understood, however, that you have a huge input file which you need to parse and translate into some output. The input is so large that it becomes important to do the parsing and translation in an efficient way.

As you have already seen, spawning subprocesses for every single part of line processing is entirely inefficient (this is what you do in your shell script, when you pipe things around between sed and awk). Also, it seems to me that you read certain parts of the input data multiple times.

You need to use a high-level programming language such as Python (which I really recommend here) and then use an idiom such as

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in file:
        your_process_function_for_a_line(line)
```

This way, the data is processed while reading the file. You can create some data structures before starting this loop, e.g. a dictionary in which you want to store your output, and then populate this data structure in the loop outlined above. Or, which would be even better, you could write your output file while reading the input file. The idiom would like like so:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    with open('input.txt') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            # Process input line(s) and perform something to
            # generate a line for the output file.
            if outline:
                outfile.write(outline)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be a lot speedier: it only has to read each line in each .bin file a single time:

```sh
for infile in "$DATAPATH"/*.bin; do 
    outfile="$OUTPATH/$(basename "$infile" ".bin")1.txt" 
    awk -F'[ ,]' ' 
        NF==16 { 
            printf "%s %s %s %s ", $1,$2,$7,$9
            printf "%s %s %s %s %s ", prev5,prev4,prev3,prev2,prev1
            for (i=1; i<=5; i++) { getline; printf "%s ", $5 } 
            print ""                                                      
            next                
        }                           
        { prev5=prev4; prev4=prev3; prev3=prev2; prev2=prev1; prev1=$5 } 
    ' <"$infile" >"$outfile" 
done
```

You could also see if this perl is faster than the awk:

```
perl -F'/[\s,]/' -lane '
    if (@F == 16) {
        @fields = ($F[0], $F[1], $F[6], $F[8], @prev);
        do { $_ = <>; push @fields, (split)[4] } for (1..5);
        print join(" ", @fields)
    } 
    else { push @prev, $F[4]; shift @prev if @prev > 5 }
'
```